# php soap client array of strings returns as an empty object

Tags: java, php, web-services, wsdl, client

Ok, so I have a php soap client which calls a method and obtains some information correctly, it can grab simple types like strings or even objects, but when it goes to an array of some type (in this case Strings) it always comes back as an empty object.  I tried casting it to array and many other things, but every option I use it always returns the same thing.

Here is some background information:

This is a web service which I created in java using the help of eclipse.  I also auto-generated a java client to test the web service prior to creating the client in php.  I created multiple test cases which used the auto generated java client (the proxy class) and successfully returned the correct expected value.  Another words, java had no trouble grabbing this array of strings and showing me each value.  I did this to determine if the problem was server-side or client-side and so far it's pointing more towards the client-side.

Next, php's soap client has a nice feature where if you set the options to include ("trace" => 1) you can call __getLastResponse() to see what the response xml looks like, so here it is:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    < soapenv:Body>
        < getAllCarClassesIdsAsWsCarClassIdsResponse xmlns="X">
            < getAllCarClassesIdsAsWsCarClassIdsReturn>
                < carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                    < carClassIds>X< /carClassIds>
                < /carClassIds>
            < /getAllCarClassesIdsAsWsCarClassIdsReturn>
        < /getAllCarClassesIdsAsWsCarClassIdsResponse>
    < /soapenv:Body>
< /soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please note that certain values have been replaced with an X for security purposes.  Also, the xml has an extra space after the opening bracket because I couldn't find a way to post xml otherwise.  I apologize if it's hard to read.

The point is that the response shows the correct values (those X's should be in an array of strings), but instead I'm still seeing a blank object.  Below is a var_dump of the full response object:

```
object(WsCarClassIds)#4 (1) {
   ["carClassIds"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (0) {
  }
}
```

Below is a var_dump of the object after using get_object_vars() on it:

```
array(1) {
  ["carClassIds"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (0) {
  }
}
```

And below is a var_dump of the object followed by a var_dump of it casted to an array using (array) $carClassIds:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (0) {
}
array(0) {
}
```

In case the information is helpful, here is a bit of the wsdl file which contains the "complex type" that is supposed to be an array of strings:

```
< complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_string">
    < sequence>
     < element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="xsd:string"/>
    < /sequence>
   < /complexType>
```

Also, I want to add that I tried already to add the "SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE" feature inside the options array when instantiating the soap client.  It was a suggestion on many forums for dealing with the de-seralization of "ArrayOf_xsd_string".  Adding the option had no effect.

I also tried adding this to the top of my code:
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
Which tells the client to disable wsdl caching, which also resulted in no change.

I put a lot of information here, but I'm willing to put anything else that might be needed to solve this problem.  I've been working on it for almost 2 full, very long days and can't seem to find a solution.  Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

-Asaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find a solution to the problem.  See, I was using eclipse's default web service axis class, the older version.  I was not using Axis 2, which is obviously newer.  It's not very surprising that the way they convert the java code to the WSDL file was different.

After upgrading to making the web service using Axis 2 instead the php client was able to read the arrays correctly.  Probably the php client was expecting a wsdl file in the newer format and didn't know how to interpret the old one.

This is the last time I'm letting another programmer convince me to use the system the way he set it up, instead of upgrading to the newest version (because he's lazy, his words, not mine).

-Asaf